# Laravel 5 Socialite Error on Facebook and Google

Tags: oauth, laravel-5

My code

```
       $user = Socialize::with('facebook')->user();
```

then got

```
Client error response [url] https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1562205014036534&client_secret=3b9807e0d826bfd66fb3fbdc627fd015&code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebooktest.dev [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request
```

and google

```
       $user = Socialize::with('google')->user();
```

got look like same

```
Client error response [url] https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request
```

**but twitter it's work**

thank for clarify

Comment: The `code` parameter should not be empty (for the FB part). Calling those URLs in your browser will give you a more detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because of the version of socialite. I downgraded to 2.0.0 and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is your services(config/services.php). check your facebook client_id and client_secret if it correspond with the one from your facebook developers page.
2. If you are trying to loggin with another facebook account to test your application in development phase, it will throw same error.

Enjoy........